# No Wifi Adapter Found - MSI Modern 14 A10M

Tags: networking, drivers, 18.04

I've looking an answer to this problem for days now and I can't seem to find it. I installed Ubuntu 18.04 LTS on my MSI Modern 14 A10M and it won't recognize my iwlwifi wifi adapter. The main problem I have is that some of the solutions I've found I can't try because this laptop has no ethernet ports, so I can't try installing packages that would fix it. I've tried installing Ubuntu 19.10 - where the WiFi adapter works just fine - but the main problem is that it has lot of trouble with temp sensors (overheating) and battery life won't go beyond an hour or two. Can anyone help me get a solution where I don't need to sudo install packages **because there's no internet at all on this device**

I have a bootable USB, during installation the adaptar wasn't recognized either so I don't know if there's anything that I can do with it to troubleshoot it.

Thanks in advance

**EDIT:** This problem doesn't happen when updating to 20.04

Comment: What Ubuntu 18.04 LTS image did you use to install it?   Was it one with HWE enabled? and a later software stack (eg. Ubuntu 18.04.3?)   Since you state 19.10 works, you could consider 18.04.4 though given what you've said it may not be for you (we used to write files we wanted to tapes, then floppies, now thumb-drives & walk them to the machine without wanted network connection?  Did you consider that?  It was called *sneaker-net*)

Comment: @guiverc I used ubuntu-18.04.3-desktop-amd64. I'm not sure if it has HWE since I just downloaded it from the Ubuntu Desktop download page. I said it may not be for me? I was using 19.10 but some software I use at college was not compatible to that version and plus the limited battery life was a big throw off. I don't even know if you - or how could one - install a package manually on the terminal without internet access

Comment: The comment *might not be for you* was in reference to 18.04.4 which uses the 19.10 software stack.  HWE or hardware-enablement stack (https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack) is enabled in 18.04.2 & later (thus is in 18.04.3; 18.04.2 used the 18.10 stack, 18.04.3 uses the 19.04 stack etc).  The 18.04.4 currently is still in QA/test thus problems could be experienced, thus my comment (but it'd be closest to the 19.10 you said worked!; ETA 2020-02-06 https://wiki.ubuntu.com/BionicBeaver/ReleaseSchedule)

Comment: Thanks I just took a look into it. It probably will help me out in the future but I'm looking for a temporary fix since I use this laptop for college and not having wifi is kind of a big problem. And getting a USB adapter or something is one of the least things I could do. So I hope to find something for my scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the same issue, here is my solution:

```bsh
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:canonical-hwe-team/backport-iwlwifi
sudo apt update
sudo apt install backport-iwlwifi-dkms
```

There is no such problem when you use Ubuntu 20.04 or Fedora 31.

Before doing that, you may need to connect your laptop with a smartphone via cable and turn on USB Tethering to share internet connection.

Comment: The wifi works well with kubuntu 20.04 beta. 

Aditionally: for NVIDIA graphics version, you need to install nvidia-driver-440 or it continuously hangs.

Comment: yes, it's correct. There are 2 versions of  MSI Modern 14, only A10RB goes with MX250, the A10M doesn't have graphic card.

Answer (score 0):

I found somewhat of a fix by updating the kernel manually to [v5.3.18](https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.3.18/) (which is the one that worked, I tried with v5.1 with no results). Is this a solution? I don't know, but I can now connect to my network, I'll edit this answer if I find any new problems by using this method. If you're as new as I am to these kind of things, [this](https://www.ostechnix.com/different-ways-to-update-linux-kernel-for-ubuntu/) is how I updated the kernel by hand.

Hope this helps anyone with the same problem. Let's hope the new release fixes these problems for AC9560 adapters.

Comment: Attach a smartphone over USB, connect the smartphone over wifi and turn on "USB modem" mode. It'll share internet with the laptop.

It seems that some kernels have Intel Wifi adapter driver broken.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is when installing the OS if your WiFi is not visible at the icon tray, **connect your machine with either an Ethernet cable directly with the router or use USB tethering of a phone**. While installing the OS, it will automatically detect the missing driver and will install them.